# Threads compartilham o mesmo endereço de memória de um método de um objeto?

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Eu procurei aqui no SO só que não achei nada parecido com a dúvida que eu tenho.

Tenho um programa em Java que faz uso de `Threads`.

```
public class Objeto
{
   int i;

   public Objeto() { i = 0; }

   public void Foo()
   {
       i++;
       System.out.println("Aqui " + i);
   }
}

public class MinhaClasse
{
   int a;
   Objeto obj;

   public MinhaClasse()
   {
       a = 0;
       obj = new Objeto();
       while(a < 5)
       {
           Runnable task = () -> {
               FacaAlgo();
           };
           new Thread(task).start();
           a++;
       }
   }

   public void FacaAlgo()
   {
       obj.Foo();
   }
}
```

**Problema**
Quando eu instanciar um objeto da classe `MinhaClasse` será iniciado 5 threads que executam o mesmo método (`FacaAlgo()`) desse objeto, e que o mesmo chama outro método de outro objeto (`obj.Foo()`). Eu gostaria de saber se, nessa concorrência das threads, por **padrão**, uma thread aguarda a outra entrar e sair do método `FacaAlgo()` ou eu tenho que colocar o `synchronized`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Threads* por definição compartilham o mesmo espaço de memória, isto é, a memória do programa atual. Para ter memória separada, você teria que criar outro processo.

Isso significa que todos os objetos de um programa podem ser acessados por qualquer *thread* e cabe a você fazer o controle disso, que pode ser feito **não compartilhando um objeto entre as threads** ou **garantindo que modificações no objeto sejam operações atômicas**.

No seu código, você compartilha o objeto `obj = new Objeto();` entre todas as *threads*.

O Java não sincroniza por padrão o acesso a objetos compartilhados e com boa razão, porque existem muitos casos válidos onde um ou mais métodos de um objeto podem ser acessados concorrentemente.

Uma solução simples e menos eficiente para o seu caso, seria sincronizar o método `FacaAlgo`:

```
public synchronized void Foo()
{
    i++;
    System.out.println("Aqui " + i);
}
```

Uma solução mais eficiente, que não faz uso de sincronização explícita, seria usar um objeto que é *thread-safe*, isto é, cujo acesso é seguro para uso concorrente e não precisa ser sincronizado.

Um exemplo com [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
public class Objeto {
   private AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

   public void foo() {
       System.out.println("Aqui " + i.incrementAndGet());
   }
}

public class MinhaClasse {
   public MinhaClasse() {
       final Objeto obj = new Objeto();
       for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
           new Thread(obj::foo).start();
       }
   }
}
```

Note que eu mudei um pouco sua implementação para deixar dentro do estilo padrão do Java e com melhores práticas, a saber:

- Nomes de métodos começam com minúsculas - exceto construtores.
- Chaves abrindo na mesma linha do método/classe/bloco.
- Variáveis no menor escopo possível (local), pois elas não precisam pertencer à instância.
- Variáveis que não devem ser mudadas são `final`. No caso de `obj`, ele já seria implicitamente `final` porque ele é passado implicitamente para o lambda, então é melhor deixar explícito.
- Método é passado por referência ao invés de criar um lamba que chama um método local para depois chamar o método no outro objeto.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta cara, mas só uma coisa em uma de suas notas: "Colchetes (na verdade chaves) abrindo na mesma linha do método/classe/bloco" ser padrão de alguma linguagem é sacanagem né cara, isso é estilo de programação kkkkkk'

Comment: @ChristianFelipe Você não vai ver nenhum desenvolvedor Java sério escrevendo chaves em outra linha, a não ser em sistemas legados com mais de uma década. Esse é o padrão oficial da [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395), do [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces), do [Android](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-standard-brace-style) e de todas as IDEs modernas. Claro que você pode adotar o estilo que quiser, o único problema é ter que mudar se trabalhar num projeto de verdade :)

Comment: Só uma dúvida: você disse que a variável obj é passada por referência. Isto está certo? O correto não deveria ser a referência é passada por valor? O mesmo deveria ser ao método foo correto? Considerando que java não suporta passagem por referência

Comment: Não existe "passar por referência" em java? Vivendo e aprendendo, meu entendimento estava errado esse tempo todo então. Ainda bem que nunca fiz nada levando essa afirmação como verdade hehe

Comment: @MurilloHenrique Eu não disse que a variável é passada por referência, mas que é passada uma referência ao objeto. Não estou usando aqui a terminologia de passar por referência ou valor que existe em outras linguagens. Quando em Java se fala em passar uma referência, é só isso mesmo. Dizer que passou uma referência por valor é redundante num mundo onde ponteiros não existem e fazer o contrário é impossível.

Comment: @utluiz acredito que o ideal seja evitar este tipo de terminologia pois como o nosso colega comentou ali em cima, ele não sabia que passagem por referência não é suportada em java, o motivo desta confusão é de que muitos começam pela linguagem C e lá é possível referenciar uma variável, entretanto achei seu argumento muito válido, é reduntante pois já subentende exatamente isto que você falou, eu apenas evitaria falar desta forma mas entendi o seu ponto. Agradeço pelo material sobre o AtomicInteger, muito interessante.

Comment: @MurilloHenrique Infelizmente não tem como evitar a terminologia porque não tem outro termo. Em Java referências são referências, todas são passadas por valor, mas continuam sendo referências. Não posso dizer que passou o objeto, não posso dizer que passou um ponteiro para o objeto, nem que passou um valor apontando para o objeto. Eu sei que é uma confusão comum, mas infelizmente há muitos termos conflitantes entre as linguagens. Outra coisa, passar métodos por referência também é correto, desde que o nome original do recurso adicionado no Java 8 é *Method Reference*.

Comment: @utluiz Muita boa a sua explicação, vou ler mais sobre o Method Reference, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O seu caso tem uma peculiaridade: você está passando o mesmo `Runnable` para todas as `Thread`s. Esse `Runnable` está associado ao objeto `MinhaClasse` atual (`this`) por meio do método `FacaAlgo`. Seria outra história se estivéssemos falando de objetos diferentes. Você precisa, sim, de sincronização, em casos como esse.